# I ask about the galois extension proof of the fundamental theorem

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

I was reading the book The Theory of Fields and Galois by J.S. Milne, and I have a question about a demonstration that is done in the book,
in THEOREM 3.16 (FUNDAMENTAL THEOREM OF GALOIS THEORY) in part d) in the proof use the fact that $\left (E^{H}  \right )^{G/H} = F$, H be a normal subgroup of G, and also $G =Gal(E/F)$
How can I justify this fact, any clue or suggestion? Thanks for the support

[image]
link of the book https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf

Comment: An element of $E^H$ is a fixed point of $G/H$ if and only if it is a fixed point of all of $G$. So $(E^H)^{G/H}=E^G=F$.